# How to get webrtc jitter buffer in firefox?

Tags: firefox, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

I am using webrtc peerconnection.getstats to get various parameters to check the call quality in Firefox. I want to get the jitter buffer parameter, but its not exposed in the getstats response (but it is available in chrome). 
Also the buffer is displayed in the about:webrtc page:

[image: Firefox stats]

Is there a way to obtain this jitter buffer in firefox?

Edit:
Adding code

```
var pc = rtcPeerConnection;(for representation coding done elsewhere)
pc.getStats().then( function (stats) {
    for (var [key, res] of stats) {
        if( res.type == "outboundrtp" || res.type == "inboundrtp" && !res.isRemote ) {
            //expecting jitte-buffer here 
            //other params like packetslost, jitter are available here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show me your code, where you look up jitter.

Comment: @jib added code in the question

Comment: Do you mean `"inbound-rtp"` with a dash? If so, I'm seeing `jitter` in both Firefox and Chrome. I'm seeing `jitter-buffer` in neither, and there is no such stat according to [the spec](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-stats/#idl-def-rtcreceivedrtpstreamstats).

Comment: yes I meant "inbound-rtp". yes jitter is available in both the browsers but I need jitterbuffer. And jitter-buffer is termed as "jitterBufferDelay" in the spec.

Comment: It is available in chrome termed as "googJitterBufferMs".